# Alignment issues using ItemsStackPanel as ItemsPanel for a Univeral Windows ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, uwp-xaml

In a Universal Windows Project I have a ListView (lvwTeams) whose ItemsPanel I have changed to an ItemsStackPanel with its Orientation == Horizontal. The ItemTemplate of lvwTeams is another ListView (lvwPlayers). All works as expected, except lvwPlayers appears in the middle. I want it to appear at the top, with the ListView occupying the whole area given to it by the ItemsPanel.

I had this exact problem in WPF, and it was solved here

[Alignment issues using StackPanel in ListView.ItemsPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490563/alignment-issues-using-stackpanel-in-listview-itemspanel) .

Unfortunately, the issue has reappeared since moving the code to a Universal Windows Project, but the WPF solution doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix this alignment issue?

Here is some example XAML that shows the problem:

```
<Grid x:Name="root" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView x:Name="lvwTeams" Grid.Row="0"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListViewItem>Team 1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Team 2</ListViewItem>

        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></ItemsStackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView x:Name="lvwPlayers" >
                    <ListViewItem>Player 1</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Player 2</ListViewItem>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you try to edit `<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>` in the style of `ListViewItem`?

Comment: @panda , Thank you so much!. Works great now. Very odd that WPF and UWP have different behaviours.